# double expression using match function in javascript

Tags: javascript

path = google.com/page/4/post.php

and some time it will another path like google.com/blog/page/ which contains the string 'page' in the URL.

path.match(/page/gi) but second path is true, how to skip that?

is it like this?

```
if(path.match(/page/gi) && !path.match(/page/gi)){

}
```

Comment: match `if (/blog\/page/)` it wil match for `/blog/page`.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: @NoyGabay page but set to false if blog found..

Comment: Why not just test the whole string to begin with `google.com/page`?

Comment: @Bergi that is just an example and I'm asking is there anything such !page.match

Comment: @user3522749: Of course it's an example, just use the respective actual domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use !path.match.

This actually works as I understand is expected:

```
if(path.match(/page/gi) && !path.match(/post/gi)){
    console.log('no match');
} else {
    console.log('match');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8zkz3dz/)